# Javascript comparison function isn't working

Tags: javascript, function

Could you please let me know why this code doesn't work? I put the value `1` or the value `2` in the `text element` but I don't get the result "this is 1" or "this is 2" respectively. It seems that the line "`x = document.getElementById("value").value;`" doesn't work properly because during debugging I have put `n=1;` and it works perfect

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Check the value</p>
<input id="value" type="text"></input>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    var x;
    x = document.getElementById("value").value;
    switch(x)
        {
            case 1:
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is 1";
            break;
            case 2:
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is 2";
            break;
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **parseInt**:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <p>Check the value</p>
    <input id="value" type="text"></input>
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function myFunction()
    {
        var x;
        x = parseInt(document.getElementById("value").value, 10)
        switch(x)
            {
                case 1:
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is 1";
                break;
                case 2:
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "this is 2";
                break;
            }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Don't use parseInt without a radix!

Comment: Thank you both for your great support!

Answer (score 5):

Values of inputs are strings. You are comparing the string `"1"` to the number `1` and they are different.

Comment: Thank you Quentin! Can you tell me how to overcome that problem, please?

Comment: You either use strings in your cases, or you convert the string you get from the value to a number (with a unary plus, parseInt, etc).

Comment: @ginter please see my answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the variable "x" into integer type by using parseInt(x).ie 
var n=parseInt(x);

Comment: Don't use parseInt without a radix!

Comment: Thanks Quentin.
is there any default value used,if the radix is not specified?

Comment: It infers it from the first character of the string (which can give unexpected results, especially when dealing with user input, which is why you should never omit the radix).